# Trying to setBackgroundColor to drawable in Adapter not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linearlayout background set to a drawable file in order to create that rounded corner look as such:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_topcorner">

     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Impact"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my adapter, after I inflate the layout item, I am trying to change the backgroundColor to a 'different' drawable, in order to change the background color:

```
LinearLayout top = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_top);
top.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.rectangle_topcorner_high);
```

The problem is, after doing that, the rectangle loses its rounded corner look and its just a plain old square.

The 2 drawables:
**rectangle_topcorner**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:id="@+id/background_shape" >
<corners android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
<solid android:color="#005577"/>  
</shape>
```

**rectangle_topcorner_high**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:id="@+id/background_shape" >
<corners android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
<solid android:color="#83162D"/>  
</shape>
```

I'm missing something to preserve the rounded corners ?

Comment: Is it in listview item? then try calling `invalidate`

Comment: can you please post Adapter full code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would share my eventual fix - 
As I was trying variants of

```
top.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.rectangle_topcorner_high);
```

The correct (working) code is:

```
top.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectangle_topcorner_high));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
top.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle_topcorner_high);
```

setBackgroundColor are for color resources

Comment: setBackgroundResource is deprecated

Comment: from where did you get this info? i'm looking at android src code and it does not say anything about the fact that setBackgroundResource is deprecated

Comment: oh im sorry, it was setBackgroundDrawable that I had tried and found it to be deprecated, i will try this now

Comment: ok that is giving me a Resources$NotFoundException and its crashing

Comment: resource not found means that a. you have no such file b. you put the shape drawable at a wrong folder. maybe try putting shape at drawable folder (not xxx)

Comment: i've just tried setBackgroundResource with your shape and it's working perfect

Comment: that is exactly where it is, and I know it works because using setBackgroundColor does NOT crash with that exception - it works, but simply doesn't retain the rounded corners :)

Comment: well, if that is the case post some more code. post your `onCreateView` and full layout. and your adpater code